# Length of 2D String list does not return the right value

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem when I use .count in my 2D String list. This is the code:

```
If File.Exists(fullPath) = True Then
        Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath)
        Dim s As String
        accountCounter = 0

        For Each s In readText
            accountList.Add(New List(Of String))
            accountList.Add(New List(Of String))
            accountList.Add(New List(Of String))

            accountList(accountCounter).Add(s.Split(",")(0))
            accountList(accountCounter).Add(s.Split(",")(1))
            accountList(accountCounter).Add(s.Split(",")(2))
            accountCounter += 1
        Next
        print_logs(accountList.count)
    End If
```

The result is this:

> {{name,email,password},{name2,email2,password2},{name3,email3,password3},{name4,email4,password4}}

beacuse in the file there are the following lines:
name,email,password
name2,email2,password2
name3,email3,password3
name4,email4,password4

But data is not the problem, the real problem is the Count method, it returns (12). I think that it returns 4 * 3 result, because if I add this in the code:

`print_logs(accountList(0).Count)`

it correctly returns 3.

So, how can I just return 4?

Comment: @JamesThorpe because if i do a for like  `for i As Integer = 0 To accountList.Count - 1` he go from 0 to 11.

Comment: `print_logs(accountCounter)` perhaps?

Comment: @Arvo i have used accountCounter because i have not solution, but is impossibile (i think) that i can not return my list rows.

Comment: @terzi_matte have you seen the solution I gave ?

Comment: @Martin Yes, really thank you. Using my solutis, it returns "12", using your code, it returns "4".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code you create three new rows everytime you do an iteration... If there are four lines in your text files then you will create twelve...

Do this instead :

```
If File.Exists(fullPath) = True Then
    Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath)
    Dim s As String
    accountCounter = 0

    For Each s In readText
        accountList.Add(New List(Of String))
        accountList(accountCounter).Add(s.Split(",")(0))
        accountList(accountCounter).Add(s.Split(",")(1))
        accountList(accountCounter).Add(s.Split(",")(2))
        accountCounter += 1
    Next
    print_logs(accountList.count)
End If
```

And if you want to make it even better :

```
If File.Exists(fullPath) = True Then
    Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath)

    For Each s As String In readText
        Dim newList = New List(Of String)

        newList.Add(s.Split(",")(0))
        newList.Add(s.Split(",")(1))
        newList.Add(s.Split(",")(2))
        accountList.Add(newList)
    Next
    print_logs(accountList.count)
End If
```